# Will the data in an IndexedDB be available between the browsers?

Tags: indexeddb

I created a few tasks through this [online app](http://mdn.github.io/to-do-notifications/) which uses *IndexedDB*. I can see the tasks in the same browser after I close and open, but not in others.

Will the data in an IndexedDB be available between the browsers at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to do something like store data in Chrome then read it from Edge: no, that is not possible.